# Reading sql statements from sql file with variable dir in perl

Tags: sql, postgresql, perl

I am trying to read a SQL file with perl to execute on a database (for testing purposes. I just print the fetched SQL query from the SQL file). Right now I have a working subroutine which will fetch a SQL query from a SQL file and print this

```
my $sqlfile = get_sql_from_file("SQL\lastVacuum.sql");
print $sqlfile;

sub get_sql_from_file {
    open my $fh, '<', shift or die "Can't open SQL File for reading: $!";
    local $/;
    return <$fh>;
};
```

But I want the SQL file to be in a variable dir so I tried to add the dir into the string like this.

```
    $SQLdir = "C:\Users\Bilal\Desktop\postgres\sql\postgres"; 
    my $sqlfile = get_sql_from_file("SQL" , $SQLdir ,"/postgres/lastVacuum.sql"); 
    print $sqlfile;
```

But I keep getting:

> "Can't open SQL File for reading: Permission denied ".

Is this because I read from the C drive...

I am really stuck at this for a long time and I hope someone can help me in the right direction.

Comment: Did you alter the subroutine to take into account that there are now more arguments? The comma `,` gives you multiple args, it does not concatenate into one string. Also take into account that even though you're on Windows, you still need to escape the backslash ``\`` in your double-quoted string because Perl will think `"\l"` is an escape sequence, and not a backslash and an L.

Comment: Try single quotes for the file path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file reading process is correct. But, you pass 3 arguments into a subroutine which expects 1 argument. For concatenation, please follow the below syntax:

```
$SQLdir = "C:\Users\Bilal\Desktop\postgres\sql\postgres"; 
my $T_SQLdir = "$SQLdir" . "/postgres/lastVacuum.sql"
my $sqlfile = get_sql_from_file($T_SQLdir); 
print $sqlfile;
```

Here I pass only one argument with the correct path of the SQL file.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick indeed .  I also followed  @xxfelixxx. and simbabque  who said that the backslash in perl requires some different string definition. The double " give back errors ; but the single quotes worked as a charm

Comment: yes if you use double quotes ("") then Perl interpolate. Where as in single quotes ('') it does not interpolate. In single quotes directly show its string value.